# Best Practice: Authenticated User and User Management

Tags: authentication, laravel, model, laravel-5

Somewhat new to Laravel and I'm building an application in Laravel 5 and I have the authenticated user who is then managing user records. I'm currently using Zizaco Entrust and have roles and permissions all setup nicely. At the moment I'm passing a user object to my templates through the controller for the authenticated user as that is the only way I can find to check hasRole through entrust.  This becomes a problem when I start managing user records as I'd like to pass user and users and use REST but now user is occupied by the logged in user.

I'm basically looking for the best practice in having the logged in user always available (so the page header has their name and info and I can always log their edits to the data) and then the user model loading the user index, edit, etc. I was looking into Model Binding but now that has me even more confused - I implemented that on one of my models and now the hasMany children aren't loading.

I had hoped that Auth::user() provide me with the logged in user info but [I can't do Entrust hasRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934449/laravel-5-with-entrust-hasrole-not-working) on that so it's unusable unless I use Auth::user() to load up the user from the model.

Comment: Seems your linked question found an answer that makes this question obsolete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 with entrust - hasRole not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934449/laravel-5-with-entrust-hasrole-not-working)

Comment: Yes! I discovered the answer just after posting that! I'll follow up with an answer..

Answer (score 0):

While it has caused an issue with my login, I discovered that If I change my model in config/auth.php

```
'model' => 'App\User',
```

to

```
'model' => 'App\Models\User',
```

That I'm able to use Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'). Now If I can just work out why doing so causes me this error on authentication:

```
ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 106:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Models\User given, called in /Users/dylanglockler/Sites/laravel-lovelaundry-5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php on line 383 and defined
```

Comment: Are your Roles set up in a database? You should be passing an instance of [Authenticatable](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Authenticatable.html). Perhaps `$user = Auth::user(); $user->hasRole('admin')`? I'd need more code to determine what's wrong here.